# How to hide the topmost divider of ListView?

Tags: android, listview, divider

How do I hide the topmost divider of `ListView`? I was able to hide the bottommost divider of the `ListView` by using `listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(false)`. However, using `listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(false)` won't hide the topmost divider. Please note that I did not add any view for my header and footer.

Below is a sample ListView I took from Samsung Galaxy S2: (I am referring to the divider on top of Wi-Fi sleep policy.)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625832/hiding-listview-header-hiding-single-divider-in-a-list

Comment: @LalitPoptani: Thanks! But I can't use the answer on the link you provided because it will be a very tedious task to hide the original divider and then add a view for each list to act as a divider. I am using a base class to generate my activities. As such, doing it will require to update all the other classes using the said base class. I am looking if there is a simple way to solve my problem. If it is possible, I prefer if it is not a trick or hack. I will still wait for some answers.

Comment: Hey, AFAIK that list-view doesn't content topmost divider by default, its better if you show us screen shot of your issue,so we get more clear about your issue?

Comment: @RobinHood: Thanks! I've already attached a picture of a sample ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topmost divider on the image above is not a header divider. It is the version of S2 for overscroll effect. So setting the header divider to false here won't work. Setting the divider height to 0 will hide it but at the expense of hiding all the other dividers. Unfortunately, `setOverScrollMode` is only available from API 9 and up. So you have no control over the over scroll behavior on API 8 and below.