# How to add footer view dynamically

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have created a `ListView` and added header with `addHeaderView`, then I called `setListAdapter` in my `ListActivity`. Any idea how can I dynamically `addFooterView` after I called `setListAdapter`?

ANSWER:
I  added both header view and footer view (actually buttons) into my list view,
but both of them I wrapped into a FrameLayout using wrap_content height, then when I do not need to be the header button to be shown I just setVisibility(View.GONE) and FrameLayout wraps to 0 height and vissualy it is not visible (same effect as if I would call removeHeaderView), and if I need to show it again I setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE) and it is shown (same effect as addHeaderView - which is of course not possible after calling setting list adapter)

Discussed here:
[Hide footer view in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317778/hide-footer-view-in-listview)

Comment: look at my editrd answer. try this and let me know what happen.

Answer (score 4):

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
ListView listView = getListView();

listView.addHeaderView(header);
listView.addFooterView(footer);    
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Comment: 09-25 18:43:52.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(229): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add footer view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.

Comment: @webaloman - look at my edited answer. try this and let me know what happen.

Comment: Just remember that footer and header are also indexed as a list element. So, If you click on the first item in list below the footer, that item index will be 1, but not 0.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to do like this

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,null);

SimpleAdapter myAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,myList,R.layout.transactionvalues,
new String[] {"transaction_date_time","user_name","site_name","machine_name"},new int[] {R.id.Date_Time,R.id.User,R.id.Site,R.id.Machine});

if(header == null){
    lst.removeHeaderView(header);
}else
{
    lst.addHeaderView(header,null,false);
}

lst.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```