# ListView not contracting when header view set to View.GONE

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a header view in a `ListView` I want to hide when not in use.  I've included code that sets its visibility to `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE` depending on another control.

Unfortunately, the view I am trying to show and hide is laying out as though I were setting its visibility to `View.INVISIBLE`—that is, the `ListView` is allowing space for it even when it's hidden.  How can I prevent this?

I have tried calling `requestLayout()` and it hasn't had any effect.

I am going to try one of the suggested solutions here:

[Hide footer view in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317778/hide-footer-view-in-listview?rq=1)

namely, wrapping my header in a `FrameLayout` and letting the `FrameLayout` handle the layout change, not the `ListView`.

EDIT: I have found that basically the same bug occurs when I added a `ViewPager` subclass in which I had overridden `onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` as a header view: it was designed to lay itself out again when children were added, but the `ListView` displayed it wrongly.  As a child of a `LinearLayout`, however, this worked fine.

Comment: try to call to `requestLayout` method after changing the visibility.

Comment: I did that: nothing.  Should have mentioned in the question, sorry (I will now do so!)

Comment: you can try with View.GONE.

Comment: I *am* using `View.GONE`!

Comment: No.  That's exactly my question: how can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added a `FrameLayout` as a parent view of the header tile I wish to hide.  This means that when I hide the tile, the `FrameLayout` shrinks to fit it, and reports a height of zero to the `ListView`, which also shrinks.  This is a pretty effective workaround, though a little weird.

Comment: Using this method, it causes issues to the SwipeRefreshLayout (allows to swipe-to-refresh before the header is completely shown). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` for **Showing and Hiding** `ListView` **Header** and **Footer**.

Go Through [removeHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#removeHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) for help.

```
View v="YOUR VIEW";//Assume
```

**You can remove Header like**

```
your_list.removeHeaderView(v)
```

And you can add

```
your_list.addHeaderView(v);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: As I understand headers have to be fixed before you set the adapter so `ListView` can wrap the cursor, so I'm not sure this would help?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)

Comment: @amit gupta but why we should not use View.GONE

Comment: @BharatSharma there is a method removeHeaderView(View) in ListView, so why not use this method instead of View.GONE?

Comment: Also this doesn't account for the situation where there are many header views: when you re-add the header view it will not appear in its original position.  In general this solution wouldn't work with a `ListView` with an attached adapter either, and a better solution if an adapter wasn't required would be a `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @AmitGupta because this will mess with the way `ListView` wraps the adapter cursor, and doesn't let you re-add the header in the correct position.  I want to hide *and* show the header.

Comment: @AndrewWyld so better add a layout above to ListView, don't use addHeaderView().

Comment: @AmitGupta Then the layout above won't scroll with the list.

Comment: @AndrewWyld in this scenario don't use ListView, better use ScrollView and add the data(List item) dynamically.

Comment: @AmitGupta ... but this is what `ListView` is *for*.  Seriously, writing a complete `AdapterView` implementation just to work around a layout bug in `ListView` (if that's what this is) seems like massive overkill.  I don't think this solution is particularly helpful or relevant, but thank you for your suggestions.  Also your original post would actually violate the way `ListView` is supposed to handle the adapter (see the doc link I posted) so I think it's misleading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40179/discussion-between-andrew-wyld-and-amit-gupta)

Answer (score 0):

That was my original code which was not working:

```
wv = new WebView(getActivity());
AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
wv.setLayoutParams(params);
...

((ListView) mainListView).addHeaderView(wv);
```

I have placed my webview to framelayout and added this framelayout to listview with addHeaderView

```
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
AbsListView.LayoutParams paramsFl = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
fl.setLayoutParams(paramsFl);

wv = new WebView(getActivity());
AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
wv.setLayoutParams(params);
...

fl.addView(wv);

((ListView) mainListView).addHeaderView(fl);
```

after that when I set visibility of my webview to GONE header became not visible.