# Button shows in emulator but not in real device

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I wanted to add two `Buttons` and one `textView` below the `ListView` dynamically. When I run my app in the emulator, the two `buttons` and `text` are shown, however **they are not showing** when run in `real device`.

**In android studio**

[image]

**In emulator**

[image]

The submit `Button` overlap add claims `Button` !

**The overlapping issue is solved now, but the buttons and text still didn't display even there has a listView.**

Latest code as below:

**under_list_view_button**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/claims"
        android:text="Add Claims"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:drawableRight="@mipmap/submit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="450px"
        android:text="Submit" />


</FrameLayout>
```

**total_hours.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:textColor="@color/indian_red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_x="174dp"
        android:layout_y="16dp" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

As I said the two `button` and `text` are added dynamically below the **ListView**, so they will not showing if no `listView`.

**Activity A**

```
footer = (AbsoluteLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.total_hours, null);
totalHours = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
footerLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.under_list_view_button, null);
btnSubmit = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
btnAddClaims = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.addClaims1);
objMyCustomBaseAdapter = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), results, listview, footerLayout, footer);
listview.setAdapter(objMyCustomBaseAdapter);

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("Project");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("Description");
                ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
                ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("TimeIn");
                ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("TimeOut");
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                        objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

                } else {
                    if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                        objMyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

                }
```

**MyCustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView


        private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

        FrameLayout footerLayout;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ListView listview;
       AbsoluteLayout footer;

        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results,ListView listview,FrameLayout footerLayout,AbsoluteLayout footer) {
            searchArrayList = results;
            this.listview=listview;
            this.footerLayout=footerLayout;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
             this.footer=footer;
            addOrRemoveFooter();
        }

    public void addOrRemoveFooter(){
        if(searchArrayList.size() == 0 && listview.getFooterViewsCount() > 0){
            listview.removeFooterView(footer);
            listview.removeFooterView(footerLayout);
        }else if(listview.getFooterViewsCount() == 0 && searchArrayList.size() > 0){
            listview.addFooterView(footer);
            listview.addFooterView(footerLayout);
        }
    }

 public void changeItem(int m,String P,String D,int Per,String TI,String TO)
    {
        SearchResults obj = new SearchResults();
        obj.setProject(P);
        obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
        obj.setProgress(" Progress : " + Per);
        obj.setTimeIn(" Time In : " + TI);
        obj.setTimeOut(" Time Out : " + TO);
        searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

  public void addNewItem(String P,String D,int Per,String I,String O)
      {
        SearchResults obj = new SearchResults();
          obj.setProject(P);
          obj.setProgress(" Progress : " + Per);
          obj.setTimeIn(" Time In : " + I);
          obj.setTimeOut(" Time Out : " + O);
          obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
          searchArrayList.add(obj);
          this. notifyDataSetChanged();

         addOrRemoveFooter();

    }
}
```

I using HuaWei to run the app, it does not shows text and buttons. But they show when running in Samsung phone...

Comment: Your java code i meant

Comment: You should be using a different ViewGroup - e.g., a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout - as a "FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item." [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: @jas posted..please check

Comment: @MikeM. So I should use RelativeLayout instead Frame ?

Comment: Your posted code is not consistent. Your Adapter instantiation is using a five-parameter constructor, but you've only shown a four-parameter constructor in the Adapter class.

Comment: @MikeM. check again.

Comment: How can I avoid this happened ?

Comment: Maybe only  the HuaWei developer can solve :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:layout_width="181dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
            android:text="Add Claims" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:text="Submit" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does not overlap now, but the button still not showing up

Comment: add id to RelativeLayout which we have placed inside the FrameLayout and get findviewbyid of that RelativeLayout

Comment: Then add  footerLayout.removeAllViews();  footerLayout.addView(id of relativelayout);

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to not overlap buttons:

1. Give the `btnSave` on the **right** of `addClaims1`
2. Decrease the `marginLeft` to something around `15px`(like the `addClaims1` button)

Comment: Can you post your changes?

Comment: In your java code you have specified addOrRemoveFooter, this is the place where you remove the footer with buttons

Comment: ya, it should shows the button if listView exists, but it only show in emulator, not real device

Comment: do you happen to know if there is any data on the: searchArrayList when you try to see buttons?